# QGIS displays NULL values as zero in the layout tables

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, layouts, null

I use `QGIS 3.18.2-Zürich` to display the table in **layout mode**. My table contains two fields of type `Double`. If I set the values to `Null` (`None`), a zero is displayed instead of an empty cell.

What should I do to make the `Null` values appear as empty cells in layout mode?

As a workaround, I can convert `Double` to `Text`, but this requires creating an additional column, which is inconvenient.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the value as: `if ("field_name" is null, 'NULL', "field_name")`

*Screenshot: the attribute table contains as well empty (`NULL`) values as well as zeros as numerical values (`0`): you can see both represented accordingly:*
[image]

Comment: This works for me: `if("kv" is null, '', "kv")`. Thanks!